# Nested loops: Access object from parent view

Tags: ember.js, nested-loops

I've got basically two arrays of objects in one view:

```
App.List = Ember.View.extend({
  students: [{ "name": "yehuda" }, { "name": "tom" }],
  teacher: [{ "name": "mr. katz" }, { "name": "mr. dale" }]
});
```

My handlebars look something like this:

```
{{#each teacher}}
  <li class="teacher">{{name}}</li>
  {{#each students}}
    // display students for this teacher
  {{/each}}
}}
```

The obvious problem here is, that the `students`-array is not within the `teacher`-array but on the same "level". So how can I access the `students`-array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be related to the view context, try to use `{{view.students}}`, I think it should work.

jsfiddle updated against comments: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/gdXfN/

Comment: hum, it seems my answer is working, is'nt it? see http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/gdXfN/

Comment: No problem :), a jsfiddle is always more clear with a fiddle.

Comment: And can I access a property from the outer loop from within the inner one? http://jsfiddle.net/gdXfN/3/

Comment: Man, you're a genius. This isn't noted anywhere in the Ember-Docs, is it? I've got one more question in this context.How can I compare a property of the outer with one of the inner loop? It seems like the if-helper doesn't really support this. http://jsfiddle.net/gdXfN/5/

Comment: The information about `{{#each}}` helper, is here: http://emberjs.com/blog/2012/08/03/ember-1-0-prerelease/ with many other usefull information.
For your context, it's a bad idea to put application logic in the template or in the view. Models and Controllers have to come. It's a more evoluated answer, I'll try to give you hints this evening when coming back home.

Comment: fiddle updated, I don't directly answer to your question, but the teacher has a list of students. I hope this is good for you

Comment: Glad you reached at what you were looking for :)